# highcharts fixed point width is not working when a series is hidden

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

Expected behaviour:
bar / point width should
be always same even after showing and hiding a series

Actual behaviour:
bars width is not same, middle bar is squeezed.

Live demo with steps to reproduce:
access the below fiddle and click on series 2 on legend(enabling), observe width of bars, middle bar's width is not same as others. I think highcharts is trying to fit the bars within the available chart width. how can I make sure bars are having equal width without space between them. I have tried with the below options
pointPadding: 0,
borderWidth: 0,
shadow: false,
pointWidth: 10,

https://jsfiddle.net/rammohanreddy201/mugp32hy/5/

```
`
```

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        pointWidth: 10,
         states: {
         inactive: {
           opacity: 1
         },
         hover: {
           enabled: false
         }
            }
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
},
{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    visible: false
},
{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

});
`
Product version
7.x

Affected browser(s)
tried with chrome, but is not dependent on browser type

Answer (score 0):

The columns have the same width, they just overlap. If you want to show entire columns, make more space for them, for example by setting `groupPadding` to 0.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    pointWidth: 10,
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/knm5xvtd/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding